# Parsing an XML and store values if they occur inside a list

Tags: python, xml, pandas, collections, elementtree

I have the following XML file (total 3 Gb, which is why I rely on parsing):

```
<events version="1.0">
    <event time="13834.0" type="actend" person="1537047" link="335909" facility="home811408" actType="home"  />
    <event time="13834.0" type="departure" person="1537047" link="335909" legMode="car_passenger"  />
    <event time="14516.0" type="travelled" person="1537047" distance="9749.86232009391"  />
    <event time="14516.0" type="arrival" person="1537047" link="79554" legMode="car_passenger"  />
    <event time="14516.0" type="actstart" person="1537047" link="79554" facility="105155" actType="work"  />
    <event time="15380.0" type="actend" person="3716370" link="280959" facility="outside_484" actType="outside"  />
    <event time="15380.0" type="departure" person="3716370" link="280959" legMode="car"  />
    <event time="15380.0" type="PersonEntersVehicle" person="3716370" vehicle="3716370"  />
    <event time="15380.0" type="vehicle enters traffic" person="3716370" link="280959" vehicle="3716370" networkMode="car" relativePosition="1.0"  />
    <event time="15380.0" type="coldEmissionEvent" linkId="280959" vehicleId="3716370" NO2="0.00273337378166616" NOx="0.33" HC="3.78" CO="19.99" FC="23.79" PM="0.00789998099207878" NMHC="3.57"  />
    <event time="15381.0" type="left link" vehicle="3716370" link="280959"  />
    <event time="15381.0" type="entered link" vehicle="3716370" link="103801"  />
    <event time="15386.0" type="left link" vehicle="3716370" link="103801"  />
    <event time="15386.0" type="entered link" vehicle="3716370" link="502211"  />
    <event time="15386.0" type="warmEmissionEvent" linkId="103801" vehicleId="3716370" NO2="0.0016834393054024187" CO2_TOTAL="5.211468969715323" NOx="0.010865835516688339" SO2="2.6488925864494008E-5" HC="0.0029077588002405412" CO="0.02157863109652191" FC="1.6554329969579966" PM="4.59119810564296E-4" NMHC="0.002754718863385776"  />
    <event time="15391.0" type="left link" vehicle="3716370" link="502211"  />
</events>
```

Furthermore, I've created the following list with links, which are of interest.

```
closed_links = ["280959", "171962","7478","7477","335574","335575","7476","7475","7474","435947","254910","254911","294486","294487","172002","172003"
,"172004","172005","172000","172001","103801","294483","310984","310985","310982","310983","652344","255111","492823","537639","485764","485763"
,"639147","485766","485765","259614","259615","259612","259613","270874","244174","540827","658808","207","609975","609974","609973","537632"
,"537631","569248","345419","259731","557381","414858","573518","468058","83791","468029"]
```

What I want is a table that shows me the `person`, if it had been registered on any of the `closed_links` (in the XML called `link`). In the final table, each value of `person` should be unique. Having the `link` in the output is not mandatory, I just wanted it as quality control to see if the code works.

My code so far does not deliver a result, mainly because I dont know how to make it conditional to have an occurence which corresponds to either value inside the list:

```
import gzip
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from collections import defaultdict
import pandas as pd

tree = ET.iterparse(gzip.open('V0_1pm/output_events.xml.gz', 'r'))
agents_o_i = defaultdict(list)
for xml_event, elem in tree:
    attributes = elem.attrib
    if elem.tag == 'event' and elem.attrib["link"] in closed_links:
         agents_o_i[attributes['person']].append(attributes['link'])

agents_o_i = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(agents_o_i, orient='index')
agents_o_i.to_csv("out/V1_10pct/traveltimes_V1.csv", sep=';')
```

desired output:

```
person  link   
3716370 280959
```

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: You if block is buggy. Could you please post the expected output for that example?

Comment: @alec_djinn thank you for the input, please see the bottom of the updated question

Comment: The link `103801` is not in any line containing `person`. How is it possible that you have it in your output?

Comment: you're right, my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `if block` is crashing because of missing keys.

Be sure you check if a key is in the attributes first.

```
for xml_event, elem in tree:
    if elem.tag == 'event' \
    and 'person' in elem.attrib \
    and 'link' in elem.attrib \
    and elem.attrib['link'] in closed_links:
        agents_o_i[elem.attrib['person']].append(elem.attrib['link'])
```

The result so far:

```
>>> print(agents_o_i)
defaultdict(list, {'3716370': ['280959', '280959', '280959']})
```

Also, you can parse the file manually in roughly the same way.

```
import gzip

agents_o_i = defaultdict(list)
with gzip.open('output_events.xml.gz','rb') as f:
    for line in f:
        if 'person' in line and 'link' in line:
            link = line.split('link="')[1].split('"')[0]
            if link in closed_links:
                person = line.split('person="')[1].split('"')[0]
                agents_o_i[person].append(link)
```

Comment: unfortunately, I run out of memory when I try to run it on my larger file.  I inserted         ```elem.clear()``` right under the last line of your solution with the same indentation. Do you have a suggestion on how to make it more memory efficient?

Comment: You can read the file line by line and parse it with a custom function. This will avoid loading all the data in memory.